# How to code an adjacency matrix from a file of a weighted graph

Tags: java, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I just started learning about graphs and adjacency matrixes, and I have to create an adjacency matrix from a text file of a weighted graph. The text file will look something like this:

```
0 4 5 0 6
4 0 0 3 6
5 0 0 0 8
0 3 0 0 0
6 6 8 0 0
```

(We can assume the matrix will always be symmetrical)

From that, we have to create a method to do a breadth first search and a depth first search. I understand the theory of graphs and the searches, but I'm having trouble coding it. Also, if you could do sudo code instead of actual code so I can still learn/ do it myself that would be great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you start by breaking this into smaller steps such as 1. Open a file. 2. Read each line from the file. Do you know how to do these two things in python? Next you will need to put the numbers into a 2D list. Do you know how to use lists? Continue in this manner with one small task at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For the depth first search I would use a function recursively and pass the int of current node and a list of nodes already visited in it and recur this until all nodes are visited and go back up the recursion to get to the next one along when all have been visited

```
check node(currentNode, ListOfVisited)

     check=0
     while(check!=n)//where n is the size of the array
         if (matrix.get(check,currentNode) is not in ListOFVisited)
         add n to listOfVisted 
         checkNode(currentNode, ListOfVisited)
     end while
```

//this code will be called when the function comes "back up"

```
check++

 end while
```

for the bredth first search I would also do it recursively but check all neighbours first and hold them in a queue then recur through the queue after

```
 queue is empty

 checknode(node, visited)
     check=0
     while(check!=n)
         if (matrix.get(check,currentNode) isn't in visited)
             queue.add(check)
         end if
         check++
     end while
 while(queue isn't empty)
     checkNode(queue.pop)
 end while
```